# Lazy loading listView from sqlite

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview, lazyloading

**Хочу реализовать:**

Есть **ListView**.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке списка **постепенно** подгружались данные из таблицы **SQLite**.

**НО с нюансом.** Данные в таблицу базы также подгружаются постепенно.

Подгружаются JSON объекты(с использованием retrofit) и вносятся в базу.

**Проблема:**

Как это реализовать ??

Я понимаю, что нужно как-то при прокрутке дергать загрузку из сети, которая после загрузки объекта занесет его в базу и потом как-то это все вернется в отображение в списке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гуглите в сторону android endless listview. Примеров достаточно. Смысл сводится к тому, что на сервер вы должны передавать параметры page и count. Где count- количество возвращаемых объектов, а page-"интовая страница" этих самых объектов.
К примеру:при первом запросе передаете count=10&page=1. Сервер должен вернуть 10 первых объектов, затем, долистав вниз, передаете count=10&page=2, сервер возвращает уже следующую 10-ку объектов.
Вообще, алгоритм можно придумать самому, я лишь привел пример.

Comment: 100% то, что мне надо) спасибо за ответ)

Comment: По идеи нужно где-то держать номер последней страницы и от нее загружать..

Comment: Подскажите как сделать такое: загрузил я 10 итомов в список при старте. Потом когда пользователь прокрутил вверх на одну позицию - я подгрузил еще один. Если пользователь прокрутил ввыерх на 2 позиции - загрузил два итем с апи в базу и с базы в адаптер? Спасибо!