# ListView ограничение количества записей

Tags: android, listview

Как можно ограничить первоначальное количество элементов в списке ListView, чтобы вначале подгружалось тридцать первых записей, затем при достижении конца списка, подгружались следующие 30 и т.д.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465931/lazy-loading-listview-from-sqlite обсуждали уже ранее

Answer (score 2):

1. Повесьте слушатель скрола на ListView
2. В нём определяйте, что достигли конца списка.
3. Запускайте задачу добавления элементов.

Гуглить надо

> endless scrolling listView

и лучше сделать это через `RecyclerView` - там это проще.

Answer (score 1):

```
youListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(isLoading)
                {
                    isLoading = false;
                    additems();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

В методе добавления доп итемов добавляйте следующие 30 элементов в ArrayList.
Необходимо так-же создать булеву(флаг) **isLoading** и после добавления присвоить ему значение true, и вызвать **notifyDataSetChanged()**.